# Visual Studio Code run individual .cs files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, console-application

Is there a way we can run individual *.cs* files in Visual Studio Code.

I have followed this link and runs fine but then I added *Program2.cs* and try to run using "dotnet run Program2.cs" but it failed for obvious reasons saying

[link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/dotnet)

> Program2.cs(7,21): error CS0111: Type 'Program' already defines a member called 'Main' with the same parameter types [csharp.csproj]"

Is there a way to run individual *.cs* files. Or any way I can run individual *.cs* files that outputs to terminal/command prompt or console.

Comment: The unit of .NET Core app is a project. A single .cs file is not a project.

Comment: And each project needs a `.csproj` file as well as the C# file.

Comment: But if your question is how to test simple C# code, check out dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: You can use csi.exe, the C# interactive compiler, to run "script files" which are given the extension csx. No need for projects or even a Main method.

Comment: .cs files are just containers for code. You don't "run" them. You run Programs with a single unique entrypoint (namely `Main` function). What you _can_ do is: Have multiple projects in one solution (with individual entrypoints, each. That will be multiple Programs, though) or have one main and control via cmd-line params what code to execute. One .cs file is not one program, it isn't even necessarily one class. It can contain multiple classes / types or one class can span multiple .cs files ...

Comment: I just saw, you seem to be using .Net Core. Handling might be slightly different there, but my comment about ".cs files" still stands.

Answer (score 6):

dotnet command is just for .NET Core and you must do `dotnet new console` command to generate a project to run it

if you are using .NET Framework and having the environment variables correctly set on your system, you can use `csc Program.cs` command to individually compile a class file to an executable. But this way is highly deprecated for any further learning or development

Comment: I have created a .csproj using the link in the original post and now I have two .cs file with main in each of them. Is it possible to run those individual files even when it has main in both files. I just need to run individual files, more of files that prints output to command prompt.

Comment: because if you use dotnet command to build and run the code, it ONLY accepts project for compiling, and you have 2 Mains in your project (project files is specified by folder in .NET Core, so as long as Program2.cs is in the folder, it is counted as a part of your project) and it cannot decide which to run.

Comment: as i said, if you wanted to compile code with single cs file, you need to use 'csc' command which is a completely different .NET implement

Comment: "But this way is highly deprecated for any further learning or development" - citation needed.

Comment: there are many unit test technologies for it, why do you need to compile a single class file

Answer (score 3):

### This should work if you want to run a single C# file in VS Code Terminal

1. Install CodeRunner Extension in your VS Code (Extension ID: formulahendry.code-runner)
2. Go to Settings and open settings.json
3. Type in code-runner.executorMap

[image: Using coderunner]

4. Find `"csharp": "scriptcs"`
5. Replace it with this
   `"csharp": "cd $dir && csc $fileName; && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt.exe"`

[image: Using csharp]

### But if you want to run a file from a project in VS Code Terminal

1. Install CodeRunner Extension in your VS Code (Extension ID: formulahendry.code-runner)
2. Go to Settings and open settings.json
3. Type in code-runner.executorMap
4. Find `"csharp": "scriptcs"`
5. Replace it with this
   `"csharp": "cd $dir && dotnet run $fileName"`

Comment: "'csc' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Answer (score 2):

For this i've always used this c# scripting engine : http://csscript.net,

very easy to implement and works very well and you can reference local dlls, Nuget packages or GAC assemblies.

It also has a Visual studio code plugin, so you can run with F5, debug ...

Comment: Well, it runs great! But how can I stop it :D I had to close VS-Code because CTRL+C did not work and I could not find the process to kill it. (So you might don't want to use a while(true)-loop...)

Comment: CSScript either moved sites or shutdown. The domain is available.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alsein suggested, you should use `dotnet new console`. Few details to add here are... run `dotnet new console` in the folder where you have your .cs file. This will then create a .csproj (this is the project file) a bin folder and an obj folder AND a Program.cs with an empty main method.

If you do `dotnet run` at this point, it will scold you saying there are 2 entry points. Delete the Program.cs created by the first command. Assuming you have only one other .cs file (your original file) WITH a main method .. you should be able to do `dotnet run` and get the result from your .cs file.

Also checkout this cool project https://github.com/filipw/dotnet-script - this will allow you to run .csx (c# script file) as individual files. So instead of writing .cs files, you write .csx script and run them as `dotnet script helloworld.csx`

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode you can simply do this:

1. Put the following line in your `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup><StartupObject>namespace.classname</StartupObject></PropertyGroup>
```

2. In the terminal, type

```
$ dotnet run
```

Answer (score 0):

### Under **Linux**

If you want use the [DivyashC  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67585297/1880664) using the CodeRunner Extension under Linux,

I suggest use the next command for step (5):

```
"csharp": "csc $fileName && ./$fileNameWithoutExt.exe"
```

Or if you want use Mono compiler (mcs):

```
"csharp": "mcs $fileName && ./$fileNameWithoutExt.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had issue with this and I was able to come up with a quicker way to do this in VSCode thanks to @DivyashC's answer of [CodeRunner execution for single file for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67585297/5559945) and answer from [Specify startup object on fly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73958861/5559945) with a few tweak to the final setting as given below :

```
{ ...
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"code-runner.ignoreSelection": true,
"code-runner.executorMap": {
....
"csharp": "cd $dir && dotnet clean --nologo -v=q && dotnet build -v=q /property:StartupObject=$fileNameWithoutExt && dotnet run"
... }
...
}
```

After which I can directly run the individual files.

Answer (score -2):

In Visual Studio Code Open the folder containing your Program.cs file, as long as their is a project file in that folder you can open a new terminal window and type dotnet build then after it builds dotnet run.

Comment: OP's question is about running individual .cs files like an executable/program. dotnet build = msbuild will ask for a project or solution file to build. It will not build program.cs without one.