# Specify startup object on the fly using dotnet CLI

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, command-line-interface

Suppose I have a console app containing two CS files:

## Program1.cs

```
using System;

namespace MyConsoleApp
{
    class Program1
    {
        pubic static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Program1");
        }
    }
}
```

## Program2.cs

```
using System;

namespace MyConsoleApp
{
    class Program2
    {
        pubic static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Program2");
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to run this app using the dotnet CLI (`dotnet run`) I'm going to get an error:

> error CS0017: Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point

As far as I know, `/main` is only a flag to `csc` and not to `msbuild`. In order to pinpoint the startup type with `msbuild` one must specify it in the CSPROJ file as `MainEntryPoint` or `StartupObject`.

In my case, I'd like to be able to specify this on the fly through the `dotnet` CLI. Unfortunately the following still throws the exact same error:

`dotnet run msbuild /main:MyConsoleApp.Program1`

How do I pass `csc`'s `/main` switch to `msbuild` through the `dotnet` CLI?

## Edit

This is not a duplicate because the `/p` switch doesn't help:

```
$ dotnet build /p:StartupObject=MyConsoleApp.Program2
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.3+5d7fe36cf for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\Users\MyConsoleApp\MyConsoleApp.csproj (in 86 ms).
  MyConsoleApp -> C:\Users\MyConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyConsoleApp.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.76
$ dotnet run
From Program1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass a parameter through MSBuild to the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063426/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-through-msbuild-to-the-compiler)

Comment: @Eldar not really. I've found that neither `dotnet build` nor `dotnet run` are sensitive to the `/p:StartupObject` switch.

Comment: If you are using Net 6.0 `dotnet run doesn't respect arguments like /property:property=value, which are respected by dotnet build.`

Comment: By the way `/p` is short form of `/project` not `/property`

Comment: I am curios, why do you need two entry points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p` switch only works with `dotnet build` and not `dotnet run` which is a shame. Also you need to clean the solution before building with the `/p` switch every time so it picks the right startup object:

```
dotnet clean --nologo -v=q
dotnet build -v=q /property:StartupObject=MyConsoleApp.Program2
dotnet run
```

It would be so much nicer if I could just do something like:

`dotnet run /p:StartupObject=MyConsoleApp.Program2`